# Problem with sbpl package

Tags: ros, sbpl, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm working with Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Electric to deal with the Robotnik Summit robot. When installing the navigation_experimental stack (https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/experimental), I have some problems when building these two packages:

sbpl_lattice_planner
sbpl_recovery

When doing the "rosmake" for those two packages, I get the same error, this one:

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
CMakeLists.txt:15 (pkg_check_modules)

When doing the "rosdep install", it says that the package "sbpl" cannot be found. But the strange thing is that I have that package installed. In fact, if I do:

rospack find sbpl

It finds the package, with this path:

/opt/ros/electric/stacks/sbpl

The path of navigation_experimental is:

/opt/ros/electric/stacks/navigation_experimental

The "rospack find" finds the sbpl package, but when installing other packages it can't find it.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39609/problem-with-sbpl-package/) by [egoitzas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2906/egoitzas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm willing to bet you're using the fuerte version of navigation_experimental with the electric version of SBPL. The fuerte version uses the new build system which treats SBPL as a system dependency instead of a ROS package. Assuming you checked navigation_experimental out from source control, you should be able to checkout the tagged 'electric' version which looks for the 'ROS package' version of SBPL.

---

Originally posted by [adornbush](https://answers.ros.org/users/2909/adornbush/) with karma: 91 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3